Plotting the following curve from the given parametric information
2023 AP Calculus BC, Q2 begins with:

Is there a way to plot that curve from the given information?
(Plotting the curve is not part of the question that follows. I am just curious, because there is no known closed form for the integral,
$$
\displaystyle\int \exp(\cos x)\, dx
$$
so I thought maybe there is something I am missing.)
